# Tooltip: overflow hidden is hold the child element content

Tags: html, css

### The problem

I'm facing a problem when shifting the child element to the top of all content. I did a Sandbox to show what I'm trying to do (it's just a simulation):
https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-overflow-9yx29s?file=/mystyle.css:104-124

- I need to keep the `overflow: hidden` property in the container.
- The Tooltip must be set inside the container `div`

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.tooltip {
  z-index: 9999;
  top:0;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tooltip">fancy Tooltip content</div>
    </div>
```

### What I'm expecting:

> with  `overflow: hidden;` in container

[image]

I appreciate any support

Comment: You have a <div> tag that doesn't have a closing tag ( </div>). Either remove the <div> or add another closing </div> tag. Does that resolve your issue? Also, what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Bart thanks. I fixed this in the post but the main result is the same

Comment: Soo, what exactly  do you want the solution to accomplish? Why are you putting content in the container that is way taller than it allows for?

Comment: @Randommm imagine that I need a tooltip that is higher than the container parent and the content parent is a kind of table row that needs the overflow hidden property

Comment: Set `position: fixed;` and calculate `left` / `top` using javascript. Or use a ready-made library, for example [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/)

Answer (score 1):

there is one way.
add parent div for ".container" and remove "position: relative" from ".container"
and add it to ".grand-parent" and you have to control the height of the tooltip.

```css
.grand-parent {
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tooltip {
  z-index: 9999;
  top: -20px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  position: absolute;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
 <div class="grand-parent">
      <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="tooltip">fancy Tooltip content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]